# git svn cherry pick ignored warning

Tags: git, git-svn

When I run `git svn fetch` it sometimes prints following warning:

```
W:svn cherry-pick ignored (/path/in/svn:<svn revision number list>) missing 55 commit(s) (eg 9129b28e5397c41f0a527818edd344bf264359af)
```

What this warning is about?

Comment: Hi, i think cherry-picking destroys the history! Maybe thats why he says missing "history" of 55commits

Comment: @SG86, what do you mean saying `destroying`?

Comment: Cherry-picking does not destroy history. Cherry-picking duplicates it. Git doesn't really destroy history normally. Rebase will orphan it, but it still exists in the repository for a time until it gets garbage collected. Until then it can be recovered with git-reflog.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

When someone does a "cherry-pick merge" with Subversion, Subversion records the commit that was merged in the metadata for the files and folders involved.

When you do a `git svn fetch`, Git sees that merge metadata, and tries to interpret it as a merge between the Git remote branches. All this message means is that Git tried to do that, but failed, so it'll record it as a regular commit rather than a merge.

It's not something you need to worry about unless you're seeing bugs in how Git picks up Subversion commits.

In more detail:

Say you have a Subversion repository with two branches `A` and `B`, with a matching Git svn repository:

```
A B   

*    r6
| *  r5
* |  r4
| *  r3
|/     
*    r2
*    r1
```

If you were to reintegrate branch `B` back into branch `A`, you'd use a command in a branch `A` working copy like `svn merge -r 3:HEAD ^/branches/B` or just `svn merge --reintegrate ^/branches/B`. Subversion would record metadata in `svn:mergeinfo` tags recording that this merge had taken place, and your next `git svn fetch` will see this metadata, see that branch `B` has been reintegrated into branch `A`, and record the corresponding commit in its history as a merge too.

If you just wanted a single commit from branch `B` in branch `A` (say r3 added a feature you need), but you don't want to reintegrate the entire branch yet, you'd instead use a Subversion command like `svn merge -c 3 ^/branches/B`. Again, Subversion would record merge metadata, and Git would see this and try to work out if it could record a branch merge as in the previous example. In this case it can't: branch `A` doesn't contain anything like branch `B`'s r5. That's what triggers this warning.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean `However, say you just pulled r3 from branch`?

Comment: Very good answer to a question about a very cryptic message.  Thanks!

Comment: @me_and In my case this is about ~500 commits (not 55 as written in the question). And it takes a long time for the git to traverse all the history and to find out that the best is just to record these as a regular commits. This is happening much of the times git try to fetch record info. Is there some modification key or setting for the git to do the same thing more quickly?

Comment: @Aleksie: Possibly, but I can't think of one off the top of my head. Try asking your question as a new question and someone might be able to offer some more help!

Comment: well, I am seeing bugs in how Git picks up Subversion commits: the cherry picked commit in branch is empty (no files changed) in git which is no good.