# Slow git-svn rebase reporting "W:unknown path/rev" and "W:svn cherry-pick ignored"

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm using git-svn on top of a Subversion repository with a standard layout.

Since we started to use branches, `git svn rebase` has become slow as hell (especially on windows machines) and reports tons of the following warnings:

```
[...]
W:unknown path/rev in svn:mergeinfo dirprop: /branches/2.0.x:3152
W:unknown path/rev in svn:mergeinfo dirprop: /branches/2.0.x:3157
W:unknown path/rev in svn:mergeinfo dirprop: /branches/2.0.x:3159-3196
[...]
W:svn cherry-pick ignored (/branches/2.0.x:852-853,855-861,865-884,3078,3081-3082,3102,3105-3109,3111,3119,3121,3125-3126,3129,3131,3133-3135,3138,3143-3144,3146-3147,3150,3152,3157,3159-3196,3198-3201,3208-3219) - missing 1 commit(s) (eg 606cd9303f245a6c93cea57ecf4d6faf585616cf)
r3222 = 240a0faa016ce74d708832a1d88e32b5f939bfb5 (refs/remotes/trunk)
```

What are they all about (*unknown path/rev* and *missing commits*) and how can I resolve them to avoid the slowdown of the synchronization with the subversion repository?

We really stick to a standard Subversion repository layout and carefully merge from branches. So the `svn:mergeinfo` properties are correct and all do make sense.

P.S.: I noticed that using `git svn fetch` at least seems to minimize the unknown-path warnings. But what are all thos "missing commit" warnings about?

Answer (score 1):

It all comes from the way SVN stores the metadata about merges and how git handles that info.

In the end you'll see on the git repo all the svn commits done on each branch but you will fail to see that they are there due to a merge.. which sucks IMO.

You can read a good explanation about why this happens and even a nice example in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9437882/1954768

I have noticed that using a git tool (eg. SmartGit) I could get this information on to the git repo. I assume that's because the tool runs a long list of git commands for each fetch. You could probably try to reproduce those commands to get the conversion done nicely... it all depends on how much you want it :)